# Relative path redirects with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mod_Rewrite with Relative Path Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102358/mod-rewrite-with-relative-path-redirects)

I have a series of RewriteRules in .htaccess for my site which I'm in the process of restructuring.

```
# Requests for http://example.com/contents/section/4/48/
# get redirected to http://example.com/courses
RewriteRule ^content/section/4/48/$ /courses [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine, except that right now I've got the new and unreleased site sitting in a `/new/` subdirectory, and so while testing, I need the rules to redirect to `/new/courses` instead of `/courses`... basically I just want it to redirect to a URL relative to where the .htaccess file is.

```
/home/user/www/new/.htaccess --> redirect to /new/courses
/home/user/www/.htaccess --> redirect to /courses
```

It doesn't seem right that I'd have to change each line in the /new/.htaccess file when I move it to root directory. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Comment: Apparently not. I can't even remember what I ended up doing in the end.

Comment: This post has the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9102921/59160

Answer (score -3):

Untested - but you should simply be able to remove the "/" from your target, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^content/section/4/48/$ courses [R=301,L]
```

Comment: unfortunately no, that doesn't work. it ends up adding the filesystem path to the url like this: example.com/home/user/www/new/courses