# Mod_Rewrite with Relative Path Redirects

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, redirect, ubuntu, apache2

I have this rule in an .htaccess file located in a directory named `clips/`:

```
RewriteRule ^mlk/?$ segment/index.php?clip=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

What I am intending is that when someone visits `http://example.local/clips/mlk` they are redirected to `http://example.local/clips/segment/index.php?clip=1`

What *actually* happens is that when someone visits `example.local/clips/mlk` they are redirected to `example.local/var/www/example/clips/segment/index.php?clip=1`

I'm not sure why it's doing this.  If I change the rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^mlk/?$ /segment/index.php?clip=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

The user is redirected to example.local/segment/index.php?clip=1, which is still incorrect.  I don't want to have to specify an absolute path in the case of these files being moved around the website's directory tree.  How can I get this to work relatively instead of absolutely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a RewriteBase directive as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clips/

RewriteRule ^mlk/?$ segment/index.php?clip=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

**EDIT**

> but is there any way to get this to work without using a RewriteBase directive

You could also try

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^mlk/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1segment/index.php?clip=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: The RewriteBase directive works -- but is there any way to get this to work without using a RewriteBase directive?

Comment: I changed the condition to be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+/([^/]+/)*) [NC]` and it seems to work fine with nested directories now, too.  Thank you.

Comment: The latter does not work when one wants the rules to work independent of where (and how deep) in the namespace the directory is located.